# Get the currently signed-in user Firebase in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to switch to a new view when the login is successful And it will save the login state, when I close the App and open it again, no need to login again. I use combine . library .Hope you can help me. Thanks

Here is my full code. Hope you will help me

Comment: do you declare somewhere in the parent of MainView, maybe in your `struct App:`,
something like this: `@StateObject var session = LoginViewModel()`

Comment: @StateObject it can only be used from iOS 14 and up. I need to use from IOS13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase will tell you... you just need to ask.
This is how you ask.

```swift
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    if let user = user {
        // User is logged in
    }
```

These are the [FirebaseAuth iOS docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) (for further information)

Your should probably call this in the init of your `LoginViewModel`

```swift
    init() {
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
         if let user = user {
            // User is logged in
            session = User(uid: user.uid,
                           email: user.email)
        } else {
            session = nil
        }
     }
```

Make the `LoginViewModel` variable `session` `@Published` like this

```swift
    class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
        ...
        @Published var session: User?
        ...
    }
```

read about the `Published` type [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published)

## Update

You should add this block to your `signIn()` func in the `LoginView` in the else instead of `session.isLoggedIn.toggle()`.

I also recommended removing the `isLoggedin` var you should look at the `user` object in `session` to check if it is nil or not.

```
    func signIn () {
        loading = true
        error = false
        session.signIn(email: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            self.loading = false
            if error != nil {
                self.error = true
                self.loading = false
            } else {
                guard let uid = result?.user.uid,
                      let email = result?.user.email else {
                    return
                }
                session.session = User(uid: uid, email: email)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the `signUp()` I added. Although I recommend making it on a separate page.

```
    func signUp (email: String,
                 password: String,
                 handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)
    }
```

Finally I would recommend to move all the login logic to the viewModel instead of the view... that's why viewModels exist.

Comment: when i delete account on firebase and Run app it still go to NewView. I want it to return to the login screen when the account is deleted